# is "collection" a reserved word in rails 3.2, simple_form or in mongoid/mongodb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am having problems with the model **"Collection"**.

I'm using **mongoid** with **mongodb** and **rails 3.2**.

I have the problem when I try create a nested resource from collection with a select with simple_form sth like:

```
 <%= f.input :collection_id, :collection => Collection.where(:user_id => current_user.id).order([:created_at, :desc]), :input_html => { :id => "m_collection_id" }  %>
```

However with the other words for the model working fine.

My question is if it's possible create a model with the **"Collection"** word with **ruby on rails 3.2, mongoid and mongodb.**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure if "collection" is a protected word in rails, mongodb, or simple_form, it'd probably be best to not use it. There are several methods that have "collection" in the name, such as collection_select for example. I checked around on a couple reserved word lists, but didn't find it there.(Here's the best one I found: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rails_reserved_words/)

When I'm not sure about a word though, I just go to a thesaurus online and look up a good synonym. Some good ones I saw for collection are compilation, aggregation, assortment, medley(ok, maybe not that, but you get the idea).

Comment: Thank you very much!. Gracias compadre yo soy español ;), he visto que hablas castellano, saludos!

Comment: De nada Señor. No hablo castellano muy bien. Aprendi español in Mexico, entonces es poco diferente. Saludos.